# How to make Future Posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

I am working on WordPress Plugin and want to add scheduled post in my plugin. Can anyone share a sample code for how to do this?

I am using `wp_insert_post()` function for add post, I guess I have to modify parameters in this function.
    `'post_status'    => 'future'`

I am not sure how to set date and time when the post get published!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) accepts an array of posts.

And among the parameters, you can set the value of `post_date` and `post_date_gmt`.

Comment: Yep. I believe it does work. Make sure that you set both the `post_date` and `post_date_gmt`. By the way, the format should be `Y-m-d H:i:s` (for example, 2013-06-13 00:00:00)

Comment: One more question, Did I need to set both? or Just set any one of theme like post_date OR post_date_gmt?

Comment: Yes, both. Honestly, I don't know the implications for posting only one date, but just to be safe.